# Как сравнить две метки времени ЧЧ:ММ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, время

В JS есть переменная `var a = '14:35'`, значение `a` изменяется динамически, она получает время. Надо сравнить со временем браузера, время браузера это `var b = '14:37'`. Если время браузера больше чем на 2 минуты, то есть, допустим, 14:37, то вывести `alert('опоздал на 2 минуты')`. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Если актуально, то также обратите внимание на: переход времени через полночь, месяца, года; на часовые пояса и летнее-зимнее время; возможность перевода пользователем локального времени компьютера на ЛЮБОЕ произвольное.

Comment: Конечно актуально !Да с этим надо как то бороться .А есь какой то средний формат часов?можноли на чтото ссылаться чтоб не был завсим от формата юзера ?

Comment: Вы не можете доверять пользователю, от слова *совсем*. Сравнивайте время на сервере. В большинстве случаев, однако, параноидальные проверки не стоят потраченного на них времени. Ваша задача - найти золотую середину между трудозатратами и "выигрышем" от дополнительной корректности алгоритма.

Comment: @Kromster дааа )окей спасибо пойду подумаю гдеж этак середина от чего базироваться

Comment: @Kromster еще раз спасибо большое

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var a = '23:59';
var b = '00:10';

//разделяем минуты и часы, часы умножаем на 60. 
//Минуты умножаем на 1, чтобы преобразовать в число
var amin=a.split(':')[0]*60+a.split(':')[1]*1;
var bmin=b.split(':')[0]*60+b.split(':')[1]*1;



//Если второе время меньше первого больше чем на 12 часов, добавим 24 часа:
if(bmin+60*12<amin){
   bmin+=60*24
}

console.log('первое время в минутах', amin)
console.log('второе время в минутах', bmin)

var c=bmin-amin

if(c > 0)
    alert('опоздал на '+c+' минут');
```

Comment: Ваш пример корректно отработает при смене дат? Например, `23:59` и `00:10`

Comment: Нет, но можно попробовать исправить

Comment: При смене дат еще надо будет указывать даты, что несколько выходит за границы описанной задачи.

Comment: Можно сделать, например, так (исправил в ответе)

Comment: @Kromster спасибо Товарищ.вы помогли мне наперед .огромное спасибо .а то потом бы сново бороться с 12 часами .

Comment: @Crantisz спасибо!

Comment: @Crantisz я бы обозначил этот момент в ответе, как "ошибку в ТЗ", чтобы топикстартер имел её ввиду.